# Обработка выполнения разрешения команды по нескольким критериям в WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

Необходимо соблюсти несколько условий для выполнения команды. В моем случае требуется разрешить выполнение команды, если выбрано два элемента в ListView (один элемент в одном, и другой элемент в другом)

Толком не понял как это реализовывать, потому скорее всего неправильно и работает.

в XAML код выглядит следующим образом:

Привязка команды:

```
<r:Ribbon.CommandBindings>
    <CommandBinding Command="{x:Static local:MainWindow.ImageBindingCommand}" CanExecute="ImageBindingCommand_CanExecute" Executed="ImageBindingCommand_Executed"></CommandBinding>
</r:Ribbon.CommandBindings>
```

Использование команды:

```
<r:Button Header="Привязать" ToolTip="Привязять выбранное изображение к команде" Command="{x:Static local:MainWindow.ImageBindingCommand}" LargeIcon="pack://application:,,,/InterfaceImageBinding;Component/Images/Ribbon/navigate_left.png">
    <r:Button.CommandParameter>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ImageBindingSourceConverter}">
            <Binding ElementName="lv_UserImages"></Binding>
            <Binding ElementName="lv_interface"></Binding>
        </MultiBinding>
    </r:Button.CommandParameter>
</r:Button>
```

Попытка обработать разрешение на выполнение выглядит так:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private static RoutedCommand _ImageBindingCommand = new RoutedCommand();
        public static RoutedCommand ImageBindingCommand
        {
            get
            {
                return _ImageBindingCommand;
            }
        }

        private void ImageBindingCommand_CanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            e.CanExecute = (e.Parameter != null && (bool)e.Parameter);
        }

        private void ImageBindingCommand_Executed(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
        }
    }
```

Конвертер значения так:

```
public class ImageBindingSourceConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (values.Length == 2 && values[0] is ListView && values[1] is ListView)
        {
            return (values[0] as ListView).SelectedItem != null && (values[1] as ListView).SelectedItem != null;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Однако обнаружил, что данная проверка происходит только 1 раз, при создании объектов, потому логично, что первый раз выходит запрет, а потом мы больше не можем получит разрешение, потому что более не вызывается метод конвертера.

Подскажите, как делать проверку на разрешение выполнения команды, если нужно соблюсти множество условий проверки, зависящих не только от текущего объекта, но и несколько других.

Comment: У `ListView` есть св-во `SelectidItem`, соответственно во вьюмодели нужно создать два свойства, которые привязать к соотв. `SelectidItem` у одного и второго `ListView`. Если оба `SelectidItem` != null, то можно команде работать.

Comment: @Bulson: Почему не как ответ?

Comment: @Bulson не очень понятно. Во вью модели создать 2 свойства, создать 3-е свойство, которое будет результатом сравнения этих и это 3-е свойство передавать команде?

Answer (score 1):

У меня не установлен `Ribbon`, так что пример с обычным `ToolBar` и кнопкой, чтоб показать нагляднее состояние.

[image: пример работы]

```
<Canvas>
    <ToolBar Height="28"
             Canvas.Left="19"
             Canvas.Top="10"
             Width="100">
        <Button Command="{Binding OkCommand, Mode=OneTime}">
            <Image Source="Assets/112_Plus_Blue_16x16_72.png" />
        </Button>
    </ToolBar>
    <ListView Height="100"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Vegetables}"
              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedVegetable}"
              Canvas.Left="19"
              Canvas.Top="65"
              Width="389">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Id}"
                                Header="Номер" />
                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}"
                                Header="Название" />
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
    <ListView Height="100"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Fruits}"
              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedFruit}"
              Canvas.Left="19"
              Canvas.Top="170"
              Width="389">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Id}"
                                Header="Номер" />
                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}"
                                Header="Название" />
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
    <Button Content="OK"
            Command="{Binding OkCommand, Mode=OneTime}"
            Canvas.Left="180"
            Canvas.Top="291"
            Width="75" />
</Canvas>
```

Вьюмодель

```
public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private readonly IMainWindow _mainWindow;

    //ctor
    public MainViewModel(IMainWindow mainWindow)
    {
        _mainWindow = mainWindow ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(mainWindow));

        Vegetables = new List<Vegetable>
        {
            new Vegetable { Id = 1, Name = "Огурец" },
            new Vegetable { Id = 2, Name = "Помидор" },
            new Vegetable { Id = 3, Name = "Кабачок" },
        };

        Fruits = new List<Fruit>
        {
            new Fruit { Id = 1, Name = "Персик" },
            new Fruit { Id = 2, Name = "Банан" },
            new Fruit { Id = 3, Name = "Слива" },
        };
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Список овощей
    /// </summary>
    private List<Vegetable> _Vegetables;
    public List<Vegetable> Vegetable
    {
        get => _Vegetables;
        set
        {
            _Vegetables = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Vegetables)));
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Выбранный в списке овощ
    /// </summary>
    private Vegetable _SelectedVegetable;
    public Vegetable SelectedVegetable
    {
        get => _SelectedVegetable;
        set
        {
            _SelectedVegetable = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(SelectedVegetable)));
            //обновляем доступность кнопки
            OkCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
        }
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Список фруктов
    /// </summary>
    private List<Fruit> _Fruits;
    public List<Fruit> Fruits
    {
        get => _Fruits;
        set
        {
            _Fruits = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Fruits)));
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Выбранный в списке фрукт
    /// </summary>
    private Fruit _SelectedFruit;
    public Fruit SelectedFruit
    {
        get => _SelectedFruit;
        set
        {
            _SelectedFruit = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(SelectedFruit)));
            //обновляем доступность кнопки
            OkCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
        }
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Кнопка ОК
    /// </summary>
    private RelayCommand _OkCommand;
    public RelayCommand OkCommand
    {
        get => _OkCommand = _OkCommand ?? new RelayCommand(OnOk, CanOk);
    }
    private bool CanOk()
    {
        //задаем условия для вкл./выкл. кнопки
        return !(SelectedVegetable == null || SelectedFruit == null);
    }
    private void OnOk()
    {
        //выполняемое действие по нажатию на кнопку
        var message = $"Вы выбрали: {SelectedVegetable.Name} и {SelectedFruit.Name}";
        _mainWindow.ShowMessage(message);
    }
}
```

Класс `RelayCommand` можете посмотреть [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/815897/222542)

Comment: @FoggyFinder, извините, не понял что не так.

Comment: @FoggyFinder, сейчас изменю.